# How to get value from array()

Tags: php

I have a code sample:
bank(id, name)

```
function getListBank() {
        $data = array();
        $sql = 'Select id, name From bank';
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$query) {
            echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
$banks = getListBank();
$convert = array();
foreach ($banks as $bank) {
    $convert[] = $bank->name;
}
foreach ($convert as $k => $v) {
    echo "key:" . $k . "value:" . $v;
}
```

I can't get value and key from array foreach. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code seems like it works. What errors do you get (if any)?

Comment: Could you print_r($banks) and print_r($convert) for us?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be:

```
 $convert[] = $bank['name'];
```

I've never had any luck using the property syntax in a foreach loop.

Comment: Not when using `mysql_fetch_object()`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
foreach ($banks as $bank) {
    $convert[$bank->id] = $bank->name;
}
```